# jquery automatically scrolling back to view

Tags: jquery, scroll

I´m using jquery plusanchor for scrolling to my anchors, which is working fine.
When I am scrolling manually, the div (view) stays, where I stopped scrolling. Now I want to automatically scroll back or forward to the next anchor, depending on the distance to the nearest anchorpoint.
I´ve seen this for example on www.gaijin.fi.
My search didn´t brought me any result yet, so I would be very thankful, if you could help me out with this.

Thank you,
BR | sam

Answer (score 0):

It will help you to scroll as you are trying.

```
var vox_news = 0;

$('ul.announcement li').each(function() {
    vox_news += $(this).outerHeight( true );
});
$('ul.announcement').parent().append($('ul.announcement').clone()); 
setupNews(vox_news);

function setupNews(h) {
     function phase1() {
        var voxNews = $('ul.announcement').first(),
           curMargin = voxNews.css('margin-top').replace("px", ""),
           animSpeed = (h*40) - (Math.abs(curMargin)*20);
       voxNews.animate({'margin-top' : '-' + h + 'px'}, animSpeed, 'linear', phase2);
    }
    function phase2() {
        $('ul.announcement').first().css({'margin-top' : '0px'});
         phase1();
    }
    $('ul.announcement li').hover(function() {
        $('ul.announcement').stop();
    }, function() {
        phase1();
    });
    phase1();
}
```